# Mapping from one repository type to another, does it work?

Tags: maven-2, mapping, repository, ivy, artifactory

I've been going through all the scenarios, digging around the web, and have yet to find an answer to this. Is it possible for Artifactory to map from one repository layout to another? This is my attempt so far...

In our business we currently have an IVY repository for which we deploy built artifacts. One such artifact is stored at the following path, with the following IVY file:

> - http://someserver:8080/com.abc.common_library/common_library_to/4.0.0.4-1/jar/common_library_to.jar
> - http://someserver:8080/com.abc.common_library/common_library_to/4.0.0.4-1/ivy/ivy.xml

For the IVY layouts I've configured the following:

> - [orgPath]/[module]/baseRev/[type]/([orgPath].)module(-[classifier]).[ext]
> - [orgPath]/[module]/baseRev/[type]/ivy(-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).xml

Now we want to expose this within Artifactory for our maven2 projects to consume. So I configure a new repository, setting the url, etc, and under advanced settings, I set the 'Repository Layout' to be maven-2-default and 'Remote Layout Mapping' to be the modified ivy-default. On making these changes I see the following message appear:

> Not all tokens can be mapped between the source and the target layout, which may cause path translation not to work as expected.

I test and save the new repository and all appears happy. I can browse the newly configured repository and view its contents, including the above mentioned artifact. I then generate the maven settings from the home screen, ensure that the correct repositories are selected that include the newly configured one, and apply this to Eclipse.

Having done all of this, I now open the pom file within my Eclipse project and create a new dependency. I specify the following configuration:

> - Group Id: com.abc.common_library
> - Artifact Id: common_library_to
> - Version: 4.0.0.4-1
> - Type: jar
> - Scope: compile

Eclipse now attempts to resolve the dependency but gives the following error:

> Missing artifact com.abc.common_library:common_library_to:jar:4.0.0.4-1:compile

Am I missing something here? This is quite an important step for us to be able to do. Any feedback will be most appreciated.

Comment: In case it's helpful, the maven2 repository layouts have been left as their default configurations:

_[orgPath]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).[ext]_ and _[orgPath]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module]-[baseRev](-[fileItegRev])(-[classifier]).pom_

Answer (score 0):

See Yoav's response here:
http://forums.jfrog.org/Mapping-from-one-repository-type-to-another-does-it-work-td6807726.html

Comment: Please see my response at http://forums.jfrog.org/Mapping-from-one-repository-type-to-another-does-it-work-tc6807726.html#a6808339. Unfortunately I still haven't resolved my issue - any feedback will be most appreciated!

Comment: Further feedback has been added to the mentioned forum entry. Once a solution is found, I'll add it below (unless someone else beats me to it). http://forums.jfrog.org/Mapping-from-one-repository-type-to-another-does-it-work-tt6807726.html